# c# save data to passwort protexted .xls and open it

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

i have a Winform where i save some Data from a Listbox with a Buttonclick to an Excel (.xls) File with:

```
const string sPath = @"User\Data.xls";
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"User\Data.xls", string.Empty);
System.IO.StreamWriter SaveFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(sPath);
```

This works fine !

And with program start i load this File back in the Litsbox:

```
 string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"User\Data.xls");

           foreach (string line in lines)
               { ..... }
```

This also works fine.

But is it possible to save it to a .xls file WITH Password? And load it back to my Listbox using this Password?

Comment: Yes, but you'd need a library for manipulating Excel files to do so, and more code than this.

Comment: This is not `xls` file, but a usual text file with extension `xls` (more likely data inside is csv). Later have no such feature as password, unless you encode/decode it yourself.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.sheetprotection.aspx or use this free Epplus: https://github.com/pruiz/EPPlus/blob/master/EPPlus/ExcelSheetProtection.cs

Comment: Microsoft Interop Excel, you can manipulate a lot of things with this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.aspx

Comment: Interop is old and tired, use OpenXML SDK or something like EPPlus.

Comment: @S.Fragkos I agree with Equalsk...don't use Interop. It crashes a lot. It's also limited to where you can use it, as you have to install (the right version of) thick-client Office, and also it's slow. If OP just wants to write to the _file_, why recommend a technology (from 20-odd years ago) which is like using a robot to control the _application_? Totally unnecessary level of indirection.

Comment: Steffen...Excel files are not text files. If the code above is working for you, then your file is not really an Excel file, someone just gave it a fake file extension. Probably it's a CSV or tab file as mentioned. If you want to work with real excel files, I'd recommend the newer xlsx (OOXML) format for a start, and find an established code library which can read/write that binary file format correctly, following the standard. That way you'll have access to the security features.